# The following classes could not be instantiated: - android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView

Tags: android

I was trying to set a keyboard view but the following error occurred
"The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView (Open Class, Show Error Log)"

I am using this version
Build: v22.6.2-1085508

Comment: Please post code so we can see what you've tried.